# transform xml to dictionary via linq to xml

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

This is my current attempt to transform key value pair xml to a C# dictionary:

```
const string xml = @"<KVP><Id>642</Id><StartDate>2012-03-01T00:00:00</StartDate></KVP>";
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
if (xdoc.Root != null)
{
var map = xdoc.Root.Elements()
    .ToDictionary(a => a.Name.LocalName,
    a => a.Value.Trim());
}
```

Can this be improved?

Comment: First - there is site http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ which is supposed to be used for code review. Second - your code is completely OK

Comment: Excellent I was not aware of this!